# Exception when Download File in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

An Exception is throwing whenever i m downloading file .
Here is Exception.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Could not find file 'F:\Caliber\CaliberCoaching\CaliberCoaching\App_Data\UploadData\New.docx'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'F:\Caliber\CaliberCoaching\CaliberCoaching\UploadData\New.docx'.
```

This is my Download Code

```
 public FileResult Download()
            {
                DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/UploadData/New.docx"));


                string contentType = string.Empty;
                string CurrentFileName = dirInfo.FullName ;

                if (CurrentFileName.Contains(".pdf"))
                {
                    contentType = "application/pdf";
                }

                else if (CurrentFileName.Contains(".docx"))
                {
                    contentType = "application/docx";
                }
                return File(CurrentFileName, contentType);  
            }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: why this exception occurs i wants the solution of this question ?

Comment: The message seems quite clear - the file isn't present at that path. I'm not sure what else you need to know.

Comment: but i have put my file in desired folder why this exception has occur

Comment: It's possible that the account running the site doesn't have enough permissions to even see the file, but the more likely explanation is that you are mistaken and the file isn't where the code is looking. Try checking the filename for non-printing characters - paste it into an advanced text editor like notepad++